# How to call core method from android backend?

Tags: android, libgdx

I can use android methods from GDX (Platform specific code), but is it possible to get libgdx method from android back-end?
I have firebase database. On android side of my game I catch any changes in database. And I need to transfer that changes to my core back-end (For example update some actors, labels, and so on). What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing Platform Specific API inside `core module` can be possible using [Interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code).

---

`core-module` is common part of all platform so you can access anywhere in your project.

Keep reference of `ApplicationListener`, If you want to `call any method`**/**`access data member` of your core module.

Inside android module :

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

    MyGdxGame gdxGame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

        gdxGame=new MyGdxGame();
        initialize(gdxGame, config);
    }

     public void andoridMethod(){
         System.out.println(gdxGame.x);      //access data member
         gdxGame.doSomething();              //access method
     }
}
```

Inside core module :

```
public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener {

      public int x=4;

      public void doSomething(){}

      // Life cycle methods of ApplicationListener
}
```

Comment: It's possible to get access to non-static variables from this method?

Comment: I tried Gdx.app.postRunnable, but all of my non-static variables are null

Comment: x and doSomething method is non-static in above code snippet

Comment: Yes, but objects variables (Like actors) are null. I set some breakpoints in my code. My show method triggered first, objects variables aren't null. doSomething triggered next. I don't know why, but all objects there are null (Vars like integer initialized). I tried to use sync threads (use postRunnable), but situation is still the same.

Comment: May I know, what was that mistake ?

Comment: I just tried to send data to another instance of my main game screen. It happened in my game because I use the ScreenManager class, there I create new Instances of each game. I just forgot about that manager, and I tried to send data directly.

Comment: Great, You've caught your mistake. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Good news this is possible and simple, just import whatever you need, for example the Color class from LibGDX

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();


    Color color = new Color();
    initialize(new Game(), config);
}
```

Hope this is what you needed

Comment: That's what he asked for, not what he needed. :-D

Answer (score 0):

If you simply call core functions from your Android code, as suggested by Aryan, the code will be executed on a different thread, which may cause issues unless you have designed your code to be thread safe.

If you want to make sure it is executed on the Gdx render thread, you should keep a reference to your game in the Android code then use

```
    Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            gdxGame.doSomething();
        }
    })
```

The runnable should then be executed at the start of the render loop (before input processing).