# Android Libgdx: Passing integer, boolean, strings, etc.. variables values from Android to Libgdx and vice versa

Tags: android, variables, libgdx

I'm relatively new to Libgdx. I want to pass a few variables such as strings, boolean, float, integer from Android to Libgdx and vice versa.

I Googled and read that using interface may work. But there is no clear explanation.

https://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=235

https://chandruscm.wordpress.com/2015/12/30/how-to-setup-google-play-game-services-in-libgdx-using-android-studio/

Can anyone help?

Comment: Use an interface in the core module, override it in the android module, pass it to the core when initializing LibGDX

Comment: Thanks @Zoe. Can you show I can do that in the codes? It doesnt have to be complete working code. Just a brief one will do.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing data from Platform(Android, iOS..) inside `core module` can be possible using [Interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code).

Create an interface in `core module`

```
public interface DataService {

    boolean getBooleanValue();
    void setBooleanValue(boolean b);

    String getPlatformString();
    void setPlatformString(String s);

    //setter and getter of different data type...
}
```

Implement above interface to `AndroidLauncher` in `android module`

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements DataService {

   String string;
   boolean b;    

   @Override
   protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
      initialize(new Main(this), config);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean getBooleanValue() {
       return b;
   }

   @Override
   public void setBooleanValue(boolean b) {
       this.b=b;
   }

   // implement other methods
}
```

Main/ApplicationListener class inside `core module`

```
public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {

  DataService service;

  public Main(DataService service){
     this.service=service;
  }

   @Override
   public void create() {
       System.out.println(service.getBooleanValue());  //accessing value form Android module
   } 
}
```

---

Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435796/3445320), Here I explained how you can access data member/function of core module from android backend.